# in classify sign = classes[pred] TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[image]

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\python\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\umutc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 189, in 
classify_b = Button(top, text="Görseli Sınıflandır", command=lambda: classify(file_path), padx=10, pady=10)
File "C:\Users\umutc\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 171, in classify
sign = classes[pred]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```
# Classifier Function / Sınıflandırma Fonksiyonu
def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((32, 32))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    pred = model.predict([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred]
    print(sign)
```

Comment: What is `classes`?

Comment: classes = {
    0: 'aeroplane',
    1: 'automobile',
    2: 'bird',
    3: 'cat',
    4: 'deer',
    5: 'dog',
    6: 'frog',
    7: 'horse',
    8: 'ship',
    9: 'truck'
}

Comment: Is `pred` an integer, or is it an array containing an integer?

Comment: pred: [0.08329813 0.10007476 0.09799607 0.09211706 0.1058976  0.11214388
 0.10537388 0.09674747 0.10261541 0.10373574]

pred is a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, you appear to be trying to access a value a dictionary with an array. Of course that isn't going to work. The keys of `classes` are int, not arrays. And even if you used elements of `pred` rather than the entire object, the elements are float, not int. What you probably want is `classes[max(range(len(pred)), key = lambda x: pred[x])]`. This will find the largest value in `pred`, then find the index of that number, and then find the corresponding value in `classes`. I don't know what module `model` is from, but if you look up the documentation of that module, there's probably a more idiomatic way of getting this.